# can't use addEventListener() on Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Hi im trying to create a toDo list - when i press on the checkbox, the task completion should change to true. As there are several checkboxes, i have used the class element, however, when i try to add an event listener, it doesn't seem to let me. There are also large gaps between each text, the checkboxes were supposed to be there but i moved them, but the gaps still appear. Could someone please help. Thank you.

Im a noob at Javascript, and i wish to get better. Do you guys have tips on how to get better, also. Thank you.

[image]

```js
const todos = [{
    task: "Revision",
    completed : false
},{
    task: "Walk Dog",
    completed : false
},{
    task: "Read Book",
    completed : false
},{
    task: "Javascript Practice",
    completed : false
},{
    task: "VB.Net Practice",
    completed : false
},{
    task: "Gaming",
    completed : false
}]



    todos.forEach(function(todos) {
        const list = document.createElement("h3")
        list.textContent = `${todos.task} - ${todos.completed}`
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(list)

        const button = document.createElement("input")
        button.type = "checkbox"
        button.setAttribute("class", "checkboxes")
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(button)

    })

    const complete = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes")
    
    complete.addEventListener("click", function() {
        todos.completed == true
    })
```

```css
body {
    font-family: quicksand;
}

.checkboxes {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` as the name implies returns multiple elements. You'd have to loop and apply an event listener to each one, or consider using event delegation.

Comment: Also, `todos.completed == true` isn't going to produce the result you think it will.

Comment: If you're using one element, use `querySelector('.checkboxes')`. If you're using more than one, you'll have to loop through the individual elements.

Comment: Since you're creating the element programmatically you can attach the listener inside the loop without having to query the DOM at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the comments point to valid problems with you code as it stands.

- [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which you would need to iterate over in order to attach listeners to each element. If you are going to query I would recommend using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) unless you really need the live reference to the DOM
- `todos.completed == true` is a [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) rather than an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)

But since you are creating the elements programmatically using `document.createElement()` you can save yourself the extra DOM query and iteration, and at the same time create a closure over the other elements you are creating in order to update them on event trigger by attaching the listener to the newly created element before appending it to the DOM.

The snippet below attaches a `change` listener, and instead of just setting `completed` to true, it toggles the value based on the checkbox's `checked` property.

```js
const todos = [{ task: "Revision", completed: false }, { task: "Walk Dog", completed: false }, { task: "Read Book", completed: false }, { task: "Javascript Practice", completed: false }, { task: "VB.Net Practice", completed: false }, { task: "Gaming", completed: false }]

todos.forEach(function (todo) {
  const list = document.createElement("h3")
  list.textContent = `${todo.task} - ${todo.completed}`
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(list)

  const button = document.createElement("input")
  button.type = "checkbox"
  button.setAttribute("class", "checkboxes")
  
  // Add the event listener before appending. 
  button.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    todo.completed = e.target.checked;
    list.textContent = `${todo.task} - ${todo.completed}`;
    //console.log(todos);
  })
  
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(button)

})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: quicksand;
}

.checkboxes {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - definitely helps, Thank you

Answer (score -2):

[`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

> **EventTarget** is a DOM interface implemented by objects that can receive events and may have listeners for them. Element, Document, and Window are the most common event targets, but other objects can be event targets, too. For example XMLHttpRequest, AudioNode, AudioContext, and others. Many event targets (including elements, documents, and windows) also support setting event handlers via onevent properties and attributes.